# ASP.NET MVC Model properties not matching database column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to wrap my head around the ASP.NET's MVC implementation.

In examples I find, users are making their models with properties where the properties are named the same as the database columns for which they hold data, and the model's class name is the same as the database table name.

But doesn't this effectively cause a strong coupling between the database tables and the model classes?

By contrast, I've worked with ORMs in Python, and I remember being able to make your model class in Python and database tables independently, and then you use the ORM to map database tables to Python classes, and database columns to properties on those Python class(es).

Is this not common in ASP.NET MVC (C#)? If it is common, does anyone know of a good tutorial and/or good example code on how this is achieved?

Comment: Many intro MVC+EF tutorials reuse entity classes like this for simplicity. But it quickly becomes a problem for a real application. Yes, some people do map entities (to DTOs) to view models.

Comment: This is not really an MVC question. I'd suggest you look at Entity Framework tutorials or nHibernate etc..

Comment: @NeilThompson
Right, but said tutorials tightly couple the model to the database. This is what I'm asking about.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: 'Cos you are looking at it backwards: you need to investigate how you loosely couple your own classes from your ORM. Solve that and you have solved your issue for MVC or anything else -  and you will learn how to do that by looking at the tutorials for your chosen ORM